# Cómo compilar con gcc

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, compilador

Programando en **C**, tengo un programa con las siguientes librerías:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
```

¿Cómo puedo compilarlo usando **gcc**?

Es decir, cuando incluyo la librería `pthread.h` debo usar `gcc -pthread`, ¿cómo hago con estas librerías?

Cuando compilo me salta el warning:

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fstat’
>   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>         if((fstat(op, &buf)) != 0){

Que supongo que es por la falta de opciones de gcc...

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Es un **aviso**; compilar, compila.

El *aviso* indica que no has *predeclarado* esa función; en otras palabras, que no has incluido el archivo de cabecera en el que se define. Puesto que si lo has incluido, una mirada a `man fstat` nos indica:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    lstat():
>        /* glibc 2.19 and earlier */ _BSD_SOURCE
>            || /* Since glibc 2.20 */ _DEFAULT_SOURCE
>            || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
>            || /* Since glibc 2.10: */ _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L
>
>    fstatat():
>        Since glibc 2.10:
>            _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
>        Before glibc 2.10:
>            _ATFILE_SOURCE
> ```

Es función solo está disponible si se ha definido la macro

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

**antes** de los archivos de cabecera; deberías de poner esa línea **la primera** en tu archivo.

Alternativamente, puedes hacer ese `#define` desde la propia línea de órdenes, así:

```
gcc -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809l ...
```

y tendríamos los mismos efectos.

Otra posible solución, tal y como te sugiere el mensaje, es que desactives ese aviso; como no es recomendable hacerlo, lo dejaremos en el aire.

Answer (score -1):

si usas codeblocks deberias usar el compilador mindbg que es el mejor. vas a settings , luego a compiler  , luego a toolchain executables y seleccionas la opcion auto-detect. y asi se soluciona tu problema . saludos